# React-native android running out of BluetoothGatt objects using most common library react-native-ble-manager

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have posted on the github issues page for react-native-ble-manager [#596](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/issues/596) my problem.  Has anyone else run into this problem?  Basically I've collected enough data to know that BluetoothGatt objects are limited and I'm hitting that limit.  The problem is I don't see anything in the library code that would cause this issue.  The gatt object calls `close()` and gets set to `null` on disconnect.

So here's the details:
connected to 4 devices (bonded), each device is set to notify on 2 characteristics.  At times the devices get disconnected but not often; app running (in debug build) for 5-10 hours then I get the message `bt_btif : Register with GATT stack failed.` and that's the end of collecting data.

I've reviewed the library's android code but don't see anything that "holds" on to references of the BluetoothGatt other than the one for the peripheral object and only one of those are created for each peripheralUUID from the Manager class.  I've spent way to much time on this issue to not have a solution.  HMOWKYMOH

Further thoughts:

- Do I need to manually turn off the notify characteristics when the device becomes disconnected or does the underlying object handle that?
- Could frequent scanning when a disconnet happens cause a problem?  I scan every ~6 seconds when I'm not connected to all expected devices.

Comment: No on your further thoughts. What you could do is force quit the app, then start it again (or any other app that uses BLE). If you now immediately get the issue that all gatt objects are taken, then the phone has a leak in the Bluetooth stack. If it works as usual, then there might be a leak in the app.

Comment: @Emil so I closed the app and restarted it.  I was seeing at app close cif=19 and below taken up.  Restarted the app and now seeing the value at cif=13.  So they seemed to clean up after restart.  Any idea how else I can track this down?

Comment: Well you could add logging on every `connectGatt` and every `close`?

Comment: Already doing that.  I'm not seeing the number of disconnects that would cause an issue w/ hitting the limit.

Comment: So the number of connectGatt equals the number of close?